# How to stop cursor from moving if an alphabet is inserted in a input[type='number']?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, input

I understand that in an input[type='number'] only a number is allowed but in case a user inserts an alphabet I don't want my UI changing.

**The Problem** -
In an input[type='number'] if a user inserts an alphabet the cursor moves form it's set place. How do I stop this from happening?

Below is my code:

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  padding: 50px;
}
input.form-control {
  width: 150px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 27px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  background: #e6e8e7;
}
input.form-control:focus {
  outline: 0;
  border: 1px solid #297560;
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="wrapper">
  <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="$" />
</div>
```

Please help me out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that javascript or JQuery has not been tagged in this question,but here is how I would have done it:

```
$("input").keypress(function(e) {
  if (isNaN(String.fromCharCode(e.which) * 1)) {
        return false;
  }
});
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](https://jsfiddle.net/myaoo5w1/)

Basically you just use `type='text'` and then check for the key that has been pressed, and try to do a number operation on it. If the result is Not A Number (NaN) then you just cancel it out, thus allowing only numbers to be entered.

Comment: Thanks a ton! I used type='number' as I had other fields on the page where text input was needed :)

Answer (score 0):

Create a function to check if the entered value is numeric or not and call the function at `onkeypress` event of the textbox. If the entered value is non-numeric, then use `event.preventDefault()` to prevent the cursor from moving.

Try this:

```js
function checkIsNumeric(event) {
        if (event.which != 8 && isNaN(String.fromCharCode(event.which))) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    }
```

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  padding: 50px;
}
input.form-control {
  width: 150px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 27px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  background: #e6e8e7;
}
input.form-control:focus {
  outline: 0;
  border: 1px solid #297560;
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="wrapper">
  <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="$" onkeypress="checkIsNumeric(event);" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! This works fine too, but I preferred using the jQuery approach as it's more optimized ;)